# Conditional Field Masking in Gravity Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, gravity-forms-plugin

Hello I'm trying to figure out how to make a dynamic or on-the0fly field mask with Gravity Forms.

Which uses the Masked Input Plugin:
( http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ ) for it's field masking.

Example if first two numbers are 55 or 33 use '(##)-########' else use '(###)-#######' .

I was able to get a static version up that uses the mask '(##)-########'

Using the below javascript on the page:

"

```
setTimeout( function() {
    jQuery( '#input_9_1' ).mask( '(99)-99999999', { placeholder: '(__)-________' } );
}, 500 );
```

"

Any thoughts on how I can alter the code to get the field to switch the mask according to the first two numbers inputted?

Here is the page:
goo.gl/8oGD8A

An Example of what I am trying to achieve using a different masking plugin: 
http://jsfiddle.net/igorescobar/ebf0ovmj/

Any help would be appreciated.